# Как в WP вывести дочерние заголовки уже в выведенной таксономии?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста по WP, постараюсь максимально понятно объснить.

Есть таксономия **label**, в ней есть рубрика **tag_ID=146**, в этой рубрике tag_ID=146 есть дочерние рубрики, а в них записи. Вывожу заголовки рубрики tag_ID=146 вот так:

```
    $ags = array(
             'taxonomy'   => 'label',
             'parent'  => '146',
            );          
             $terms = get_terms($ags);
                 foreach($terms as $term){
                 $zagolovok_glav = $term->name;
                 echo $zagolovok_glav;
                 }
```

А как вывести дочерние заголовки записей переменной **$zagolovok_glav**?

Иерархия такая:

```
 label (таксономия)
     rubric_1 (tag_ID=146)
        subrubric1 (вывожу с переменной $zagolovok_glav)
            post1
            post2
            post3
            post4
        subrubric2 (вывожу с переменной $zagolovok_glav)
            post5
            post6
        subrubric3 (вывожу с переменной $zagolovok_glav)
            post7
            post8           
        subrubric4 (вывожу с переменной $zagolovok_glav)
            post9
            post10
        subrubric5 (вывожу с переменной $zagolovok_glav)
            post11
            post12          
     rubric_2       
     rubric_3
```

Нужно вывести заголовки записей, условно post. Это возможно?

Comment: Возможно. Используйте [WP_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#taxonomies) и используйте параметры таксономий.

Comment: А без WP_Query невозможно?

Comment: Можете использовать [get_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts#example_37501), но сути это не поменяет, Вам же нужно каким-то образом сделать запрос на вывод нужных записей. [get_tems()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms) получает только таксономии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно, как я уже и писал в комментариях, Вы можете использовать [WP_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#taxonomies) или [get_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts#example_37501). Давайте воспользуемся `get_posts()`. В принципе, все что Вам нужно, это указать тип записей имя таксономии и ее ID в массиве `tax_query`.

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'label',
    'parent'   => 146,
]);

if (!empty($terms)) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->name;
    
        $posts = get_posts([
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                   'taxonomy' => 'label',
                   'field'    => 'id',
                   'terms'    => [$term->term_id]
                ]
            ],
           'post_type' => 'post', // Или другой пост тайп
           'posts_per_page' => -1
        ]);

        foreach($posts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <!-- Заголовок с ссылкой -->
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого, получилось! Simon, спасибо огромное!